# How Can i add another background img or color just for the title?

Tags: html, css, error-handling, mobile-website

```css
.title{
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(22, 20, 16, 0.658);
    border: dotted;
    border-radius:55px;
    /* border-collapse:collapse; */
    border-color: rgba(255, 105, 180, 0.514);
    text-align:auto;
    background-image: url('https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/442/979/png-transparent-sliced-orange-fruit-illustration-symmetry-area-food-symbol-app-orange-player-food-symmetry-color.png');
    background-position: right;
    background-size: 210px;
```

```html
<header>
            <h1 class="title">MENU <br> 
            VEG & NON-VEG </h1>
        </header>
```

[https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/442/979/png-transparent-sliced-orange-fruit-illustration-symmetry-area-food-symbol-app-orange-player-food-symmetry-color.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moFjJ.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you what to achieve?

Comment: I might be easiest to just edit the images together into one image. There is no standard way of doing this... -edit *** I am wrong

Comment: You can be more specific with your question which will help you get exact answer that you need. Do you mean that apart from that background that you have already applied, you need an additional background image specifc to the title text there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many layers as you want for all background properties.

MDN Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds

You might have been having a problem with this because your image looks like it has a transparent background, but its actually just a checkered background

```css
.title{
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(22, 20, 16, 0.658);
    border: dotted;
    border-radius:55px;
    /* border-collapse:collapse; */
    border-color: rgba(255, 105, 180, 0.514);
    text-align:auto;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), url('https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/442/979/png-transparent-sliced-orange-fruit-illustration-symmetry-area-food-symbol-app-orange-player-food-symmetry-color.png');
    background-size: cover, 210px;
    background-position:  left, right;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <h1 class="title"> MENU <br> 
            VEG & NON-VEG </h1>
        </header>
```